# How to view files on beaglebone that I mounted as mass storage device

Tags: usb, beagleboneblack

I modified the boot script to make the USB mass storage drive writeable when I plug in my BeagleBone Black.

/opt/scripts/boot/am335x_evm.sh

```
usb_ms_ro=0
```

How do I access this directory from the command line when I SSH into the BeagleBone?